# Using handles for memory management - Context sensitive pointers

Tags: c++, memory

I have a polymorphic class `MemoryManager` that manages objects allocated dynamically. When you allocate an object, you always do so via an instance of a `MemoryManager`, and it returns to you a handle to the object it allocated for you. The `MemoryManager` is free to move around the object in memory, and when you need it you call `MemoryManager::lock` and it temporarily locks the object so you can access it via a pointer. I need such a class to implement heap compacting.

While there isn't anything impossible to implement with this class, I have a problem when it comes to wrapping the handles it returns into a class of their own, `Handle<T>` (where `T` is the type of the object you have a handle to). `Handle<T>` must hold the integer handle the `MemoryManager` returns, but it also must know which instance of the `MemoryManager` manages the handled object. It therefore has to have internally a... Handle to the `MemoryManager`.

`Handle<T>` *could* have a regular pointer to the `MemoryManager`. But that means the `MemoryManager` itself cannot be moved in memory. It also means we have no control over its lifetime: if the programmer isn't careful the pointer might dangle eventually.

The standard library types don't have this problem, because for them `std::allocator` is a template parameter. The class already knows who is managing the memory. But I'd like to stay away from that solution if I can, since, logically, if i use a `Handle<T>` I don't *really* care who is handling the `T`.

What's more, garbage collected languages like C# don't have this problem either, because they only have *one* instance of the `MemoryManager`: the garbage collector is global. But I would also like to stay away from this solution, because global variables...

How do I solve this?

Comment: You can hold `shared_ptr<MemoryManager>` with private constructor and public static factory method to create only shared_ptr instance. or maybe better make MemoryManager copyable to pass around and store its state in internal shared_ptr.

Comment: Who manages and moves around the `MemoryManager`? Is there a `MemoryManager` that allocates `MemoryManager`s? Who manages **that** memory manager? The way you describe it, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Igor Can't the `MemoryManager` manage itself?

Comment: How would you access it if it can move itself in memory? To obtain a pointer to it, you would need to call `lock`, but to call `lock`, you would need to obtain a pointer.